# How to skip maven default deploy rather using deploy plugin in pom?

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin

I've added deploy plugin in my pom and it works to deploy the file with customized name, `app-service-0.1-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar`.

```
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>deploy-file</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy-file</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <repositoryId>app-snapshots</repositoryId>
              <file>target\app-service-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</file>
              <url>https://artifactory.intranet.app.com/artifactory/mvn-snapshot-local</url>
              <groupId>com.app.test</groupId>
              <artifactId>app-service</artifactId>
              <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
              <files>target\app-service.jar</files>
              <classifiers>int</classifiers>
              <types>jar</types>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

However, since the default deploy still kicks in, the file is deployed in the default name too, `app-service-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` . Is there a way to suppress the default deploy?

Answer (score 2):

Change the execution ID from `deploy-file` to `default-deploy`. This overrides Maven's default execution to do what you want. See the [Maven docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-default-execution-ids.html) and [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19057054/944849).

Answer (score 1):

Just add `<configuration><skip>true</skip></configuration>` under the plugin level.